# php to display WordPress posts from subfolder on root php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure that someone can show me how to do this.. My search online seems to be fruitless..

I am needing to display some Wordpress posts from a subfolder installation of WordPress (/news) and I want to call in just some posts to a static page (as this was designed and built before my involvement) in the root directory (for this instance I have made a test.php file.

Does anyone know a way to call a loop from the subfolder installation to display posts on the test.php file?

Any help would be great.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to access the loop in a wordpress installation in a sub folder because that loop isn't running if you don't hit that index.php page.  However there is a very good solution for doing this and I have used it myself in a very similar situation.

There is a great plugin called [json-api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) for wordpress that you can install on your subfolder /news and it will allow you to easily get the posts from that wordpress install from anywhere else.  Your call may look something like:

```
/news/api/posts
```

Which would give you the blog posts from that news install in json format.  It's very easy to install and it works like a charm.  This plugin is scheduled to move into the Wordpress Core in Wordpress 4.1 https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/json-api/ which is a very good sign of it's stability.

Comment: Found a way to use rss to get it the way the client wants :) Thanks for your help :)